# how to upgrade the sqlite database without lost data?

Tags: sqlite, upgrade

I have an application in C# that uses System.Data.SQLite. In my case I use a recent version of SQL Lite database, by now I can see that the new versión has released, and int sqlite.org webpage says that is recommended to upgrade the database.

My question is how to upgrade without lost the information in my actual database.

How can I chech the version of the data

Thanks.

EDIT: what I mean is when I create a new database with the sqlite3 library, I guess that the database file, my database.db has a version. When I update the sqlite3 library, I am update the sqlite3 command line, but the database file still has the version that had when I created it.

So if in the new versions for example add new features to the database, for example triggers, foreign keys and so on, if I am not wrong, this features must be in the database file, not in the sqlite3 library, because when I access to the database for example with entity framework, I don't use sqlite3 library, I use System.SQLite.Data library.

am I wrong? the datafile is never update and only the library can be updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the SQLite library will not have any effect on your database file.

Changes like foreign keys do not affect the database file.
The last change that affected the file format was [a long time ago](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#schemaformat).

Comment: Then what is update is the sqlite library and not the database file? The database file is not updated never? I mean that in the past it was added support for triggers, foreign keys... If I am not wrong, this would be in the database file, not the sqlite library.